# Probability generating function question.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is the question I am trying to solve
Let $X_1,\, X_2,\, X_3, \ldots$ be i.i.d. random variables with common distribution function $F$. Let $\nu ≥ 1$ an independent, integer-valued variable with generating function $\Bbb{P}$, and define $Y : =\max\{X_1,\, X_2,\, X_3, \ldots,\, X_{\nu}\}$. Show that $Y$ has distribution function $\Bbb{P}(F(\cdot))$.

I have worked out that the probability $y$ will be smaller than the $\max\{x_1,\, x_2,\, x_3, \ldots,\, x_{\nu}\}$ to be $(F(y))^{\nu}$ however I assumed that this was the distribution function. I cannot find a way to incorporate the probability generating function. I can see how it fits together but cannot justify it.. any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Using independence,
$$ \mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}\leq y,\nu=n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}\leq y)\mathbb{P}(\nu=n)$$

As you said in the question, since the $X_i$ are iid, it follows that
$$ \mathbb{P}(\max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}\leq y)=F(y)^n $$
Therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}\leq y)\mathbb{P}(\nu=n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\nu=n)F(y)^n=P(F(y))$$
as desired.